# Minifying Angular not updating templates?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, aem, minify

Fairly new to developing in angular so please bear with me.
I happen to be developing components for AEM 6.2 using angular using gulp to minify the js for all the components by doing the following in the gulpfile:

```
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var pump = require('pump');
var gp_concat = require('gulp-concat');
var gp_rename = require('gulp-rename');
var gp_ignore = require('gulp-ignore');
var gp_htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin');
var templates = require('gulp-angular-templatecache');

var paths = require('../paths');
var utils = require('../utils');

var base = [
  paths.APP,
  paths.ETC,
  paths.DESIGN
];

gulp.task('minify', function () {
  var filesToInclude = ['**/app/components/**/*.js '];
  var excludeCondition = '**/*.spec*.js'
  return gulp.src(filesToInclude)
    .pipe(gp_ignore.exclude(excludeCondition))
    .pipe(gp_concat('all.concat.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
    .pipe(gp_rename('all.min.js'))
    .pipe(plugins.ngAnnotate())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Now the minification of the js works perfect. However, in the templates (i.e. the html for each component), the references to the controller aren't using the minified name. For example, instead of the minified controller name, it's still using the original controller name:

```
<section data-ng-controller="MyController as mc" ng-cloak>
  <div class="mc-name">
    Hi, {{mc.userName}}
  </div>
</section>
```

Again, I'm fairly new to angular so I'm not sure how the templates and controllers are linked in such a way that the minification knows to update all references.  Could someone help shed some light on what I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: Minification does not change the name of controllers. Controller, module, service, and factory names are string literals and would naturally not be changed by a minifyer

Comment: @JoelCDoyle Thanks! That definitely cleared things up!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue a little while back in AEM6.1 and from memory it was related to competing versions of minification IE: YUI Compressor. I'm stretching my memory, but I believe the 6.1 version of YUI Compressor was seriously outdated. I recall it being updated in 6.2, but I would still suspect it may be competing with your angular minification, probably ^latest. Essentially, you are trying to minify twice, again probably with different versions of YUI Compressor.

Now you could turn off minification in AEM, and simply run with the Angular minification (in theory), but I wouldn't suggest doing that as it would mean any AEM clientLibs are not minified.

Alternatively, don't minify with angular compiler, allow AEM to do the minification for you. Which I think is what I did at the time. Although I recall getting a hotfix through adobe daycare at some point for the same, so I can't be certain, it was a couple of years ago now.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use the controller with vm and injector syntax

```
`rmToolkit.controller('QuestionsCtrl', QuestionsCtrl);
 QuestionsCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$stateParams', '$state','Data_Service'];
 function QuestionsCtrl($scope, $rootScope,) {
   var vm = this;
}`
```

Hopes this syntax will resolve the minification issues